# What does the bar mean in $M = G \wr H = B \bar{H}$?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, characters, semidirect-product

Currently, I am going through Chapter 25 of [Character theory of finite groups](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=GjyWI91FAZQC&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=Character%20theory%20of%20finite%20groups&ots=4lExSdAZAq&sig=knazW3rtYizIjo6Z1wnX2o4JQFw#v=onepage&q=Character%20theory%20of%20finite%20groups&f=false) by Bertram Huppert.

On page $343$, there is a lemma on semidirect products. It starts as follows.

> 25.5 Lemma. Let $M = G \wr H = B \bar{H}$ be the wreath-product as described in 25.1.

**My question:**

- What is the meaning of $\bar{H}$?

Comment: Page 343 is not available in my google preview.

Comment: @arctictern, I think I have found the answer. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer on page 338.

Let me quote it here.

> $\alpha$ with $(f, h) \alpha = h$ is an epimorphism of $G \wr H$ onto
>   $H$ and
>
> $$ \ker \alpha = B = \{(f, 1) | f: \Omega \to G\} $$
>
> is isomorphic t $G \times \ldots \times G$. $B$ has a complement
>
> $$ \bar{H} = \{(e, h) | h \in H\} $$
>
> in $G \wr H$, where $e(j) = 1$ for all $j \in \Omega$ and $\bar{H}
>  \cong H$ .